# Heroku git push heroku master fails

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, push

So, I'm trying to run the `git push heroku master` command but I constantly get

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 51: Bad configuration option: AllowUsers`
`/etc/ssh/ssh_config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options`
`fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

I've done a bit of research and added my username to AllowUsers field in ssh_config, `pip` installed ssh and sshd on my virtualenv and on my root but nothing worked. I've tried push-ing from either the virtualenv (I mean the virtualenv was activated) and from the root (as root and as a simple user) but still the same error.

What else can I do to fix this? I've also read that I should try to attempt a login on heroku and then try to push. The login was successful but the push wasn't. I don't know what else to try. Also I've restarted ssh after changing the allowedUsers.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Can comment/remove `AllowUsers` to see if push works?

Comment: Well, it did help me get rid of this issue (althouth now I stepped into another). Thank your for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config: line 51: Bad configuration option: AllowUsers
```

`ssh_config` is the wrong file. The "AllowUsers" directive should go in the `sshd_config` (note the "d") file on the server that these users would be connecting to.

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is the typical name for the system-wide OpenSSH *client* configuration file. It's read by the `ssh` program when making an ssh connection to another server. The options which can go in this file are documented [here](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) and "AllowUsers" isn't one of them.

"AllowUsers" is an OpenSSH *server* configuration option. It should go in the *server* configuration file on the host which would receive incoming connections from these users. The server program is named [`sshd`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd) and its configuration file would typically be [`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config).